# rendering d3.js library visualizations for colorbrewer

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement [a tutorial called 'Mapping Minimum Wages in Europe'](http://blog.mondula.com/mapping-minimum-wages-europe) to render a d3 map of the European Union, visualizing data across the different component nations.

When I try to execute the last step of the tutorial, incorporating [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) with the d3.js library to colour the countries in a different way based on the data, using the following function:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "eu.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "data.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, europe, data) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);

    var quantize = d3.scale.quantile()
             .domain(d3.extent(d3.values(data), function (d) { return d.value; }))
             .range(d3.range(6)),
        cb = "Reds";

    function fill(datum, index) {
          var iso = datum.properties.iso_n3,
               val = data[iso] && data[iso].value;
          if (val) {
              var c = colorbrewer[cb][6][quantize(val)];
              return c;
          } else {
              return "lightgray";
          }
    }


    var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var eu = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.europe),
        countries = eu.features;

    projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0])

    var b = path.bounds(eu),
        s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
        t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

    projection.scale(s).translate(t);

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(countries)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "country")
        .classed("eu-country", isEuCountry);

    svg.selectAll(".eu-country")
        .style("fill", fill);
}
```

the program crashes and my browser loads nothing.

I've narrowed it down to that code there.

Perhaps someone more familiar with Javascript might be able to figure out what is going wrong here.

The files named in the component:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "eu.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "data.json")
    .await(ready);
```

are in the same directory as my `index.html` file. So that isn't the issue.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "it crashes" and how did you narrow it down to the code you posted?

Comment: Can you (upload somewhere and) add links to those 2 files (eu.json, data.json), so it is possible to replicate the code at another computer?
Meanwhile, you may be interested in this EU map topojson example: http://bl.ocks.org/michalskop/001f6182db52d08f4925

Comment: I figured out the problem and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include the coldbrewer, like a java `#include` statement, in this way

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
```